# SQL get dates later than specified date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm working on a database that stores a date column in a human-readable format. This seems to make it tricky to work out rows where a given date is later than.

The format is stored like **20 November, 2018**

I'm trying to return all rows where the collection_date is later than **5 November, 2018**

I've tried the following query which throws an error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE collection_date >= CONVERT(datetime, '20181105')
```

This throws the following error message:

[image]

Here's my DB info:

[image]

UPDATE 1:
I'm trying the following query. None of the previous queries have worked so far, all producing 0 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM `orders` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('collection_date', '%d %M, %Y') >= 2018-11-05
```

This also does not work

Comment: You could save yourself a world of pain, and just store dates as dates.

Comment: `Convert` is a function of T-SQL (so SQL Server), for MySql use [str_to_date](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)

Comment: "Convert is a function of T-SQL (so SQL Server), for MySql use" @ZoharPeled  MySQL also supports CONVERT  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert to convert between charsets and cast between types.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. I work mostly with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually... you have to apply `STR_TO_DATE` on the `collection_date` column because that is where the human readable dates are. As for the *input* date, just specify it in `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
SELECT *
FROM `orders` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(collection_date, '%e  %M, %Y') >= '2018-11-05'
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you want [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM `orders` o
WHERE collection_date >= Str_To_Date(datetime, '%e %M, %Y');
```

`CONVERT()` with this syntax is a SQL Server function.

Comment: `str_to_dateime` ... new function?

Comment: "CONVERT() is a SQL Server function." MySQL also supports CONVERT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert to convert between charsets and cast between types

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Of course, you are right.  I was focusing on the particular syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The value comes first in the [convert()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) function

```
WHERE collection_date >= CONVERT('2018-11-05', date)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/65799)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `STR_TO_DATE()` function

```
SELECT * 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE collection_date >= STR_TO_DATE('20181105', '%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(collection_date, '%d %M, %Y') >= '2018-11-05'  
AND collection_time = '4:00 PM'  
ORDER BY `orders`.`collection_date`  DESC
```